# Make extra newline in prerequisite in define recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to create a Makefile which uses a recipe created using the define syntax. However, I have run into a problem where Make believes that the last prerequisite has a newline appended to it, resulting in a "no rule found" error. A minimal working example is given below, the problem is triggered by trying to make the foo/bar target.

```
foo:
    mkdir foo

define FIZZ
foo/bar: foo
    touch foo/bar
endef

$(call FIZZ)
```

The exact error message is

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo
', needed by 'foo/bar'. Stop.
```

I have tried versions 4.1 and 4.2.1 of GNU Make.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong (or is this a bug)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is expand the variable `FIZZ` to inject the
definition of the target `foo/bar` (its prerequisites and recipe) into the
expanded makefile. `$(call FIZZ)` is not the tool for that:

```
$(call variable,param,param,...)
```

may behave surprisingly if the arguments contain embedded whitespace. You want
[8.9 The eval Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html),
as in:

**Makefile**

```
foo:
    mkdir foo

define FIZZ
foo/bar: foo
    touch foo/bar
endef

$(eval $(FIZZ))
```

Then you'll get:

```
$ make foo/bar
mkdir foo
touch foo/bar
```